# Sorting NSOrderedSet using NSSortDescriptor

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, nssortdescriptor, nsorderedset

When executing this code:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [Characteristic sortDescriptor];
[workingSet sortUsingComparator:[sortDescriptor comparator]];
```

I get this error:

```
*** -[NSMutableOrderedSet sortUsingComparator:]: comparator cannot be nil
```

`sortDescriptor` is non-nil, so I've no idea why this doesn't work.

I can work around the problem with the code below, which works perfectly:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [Characteristic sortDescriptor];
NSArray *workingArray = [[workingSet array] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
workingSet = [NSMutableOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:workingArray];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out the [NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) reference for the difference between the two methods

A typical usage for the first method would be something like this

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {

    if ([obj1 integerValue] > [obj2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }

    if ([obj1 integerValue] < [obj2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

(Example from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html))

Where as the second method would be more like:

```
NSSortDescriptor *nameSort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:nameSort];

NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Comment: So why doesn't NSSortDescriptor's `-comparator` method produce a comparator that works with `-sortedArrayUsingComparator:` or `-sortUsingComparator:`?

Comment: Although your sortDescriptor is `!= nil` I would guess that `-comparator` is returning `nil`. It's not very clear from the docs but it looks like it only returns a comparator if you created the descriptor with one e.g. using `sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:comparator:`.

Comment: Ugh. That makes sense. But ugh.